# Android localization values-** folder names

Tags: android, localization, locale

I have seen several conflicting tables that show localizations and what names they should take

A lot of them suggest that there are versions of the language for each country, which is fine, for languages like English, Spanish and Chinese, where I can choose to make a `values-en` folder or a `values-en_US` folder if I want to make it more specific

but some other languages like greek have a locale name `el_GR` , can I just make a folder names `values-el` or does it HAVE to be `values-el_GR`

thats just an example and I don't trust the tables I have read, and the android developer guide does not nearly list the available locales

Answer (score 44):

The folder name of Android string files is formatted as the following:

- without region variant: `values-[locale]`
- with region variant: `values-[locale]-r[region]`
- For example: `values-en`, `values-en-rGB`, `values-el-rGR`.

In your case, you just need to create a folder `values-el` for the Greek translation, and `values-el-rGR` for the country-specific Greek translation.

Also, you can make use of the resources fallback mechanism in Android, to allow particular strings to be further translated locally.

For example, suppose you have a string called “R.string.title” and the locale is ‘el-GR’, Android will look for a value of “R.string.title” by searching the files in the following order:

- `res/values-el-rGR/strings.xml`
- `res/values-el/strings.xml`
- `res/values/strings.xml`

Therefore, you can just put the country-specific translation inside the `res/values-el-rGR/strings.xml`, and let the `res/values-el/strings.xml` stores the general translations.

It can avoid duplicating your strings in different language files by utilizing this fallback mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried Custom Locale with Android Emulator it doesn't see the region folders. I changed emulator language and everything is fine. Don't trust emulator Custom Locale function guys.

Comment: So is it possible to just have, say, `values-en` without default `values`? I'm having to deal with duplicate strings and I think it's be to just have `values-en`. What do you think?

Comment: We have set the locale on device to sr-ME and sr-RS respectively, but have single values-sr folder as common strings. For some reason, the fallback works for sr-RS, but not for sr-ME. I've not explicitly created values-sr-rME, but should I?

Answer (score 5):

Right click "res" folder in your project. Pick > New > Android resource file > Localization - and it will offer you all the possible Language and Locales options and even create required folders.

Answer (score 0):

all can find in https://developer.android.com/index.html

1. in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

the page descript multiple resouce define, like drawable , value

2. in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

the page provide Language res define，
it‘s import How Create Locale Directories and Resource Files .

the format is `<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]`.

and the `language code` `country code` reference https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

language
ISO 639 alpha-2 or alpha-3 language code, or registered language subtags up to 8 alpha letters (for future enhancements). When a language has both an alpha-2 code and an alpha-3 code, the alpha-2 code must be used. 
You can find a full list of valid language codes in the IANA Language Subtag Registry (search for "Type: language"). 
https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

country (region)
ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code or UN M.49 numeric-3 area code. You can find a full list of valid country and region codes in the IANA Language Subtag Registry (search for "Type: region").

https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

Other reference： https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2