# What should be the values folder name for Serbian (Latin,Serbia) (sr-rs-latn) language?

Tags: android, localization

I want to add Serbian Latin, Serbia language to my android app. However I am not able to figure out what should be name of values folder. 
I tried values-sr-rRS-Latn but Android studio gave error.

I also referred to other thread with similar topic but it did not help.

[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

[How to include 2 variants of Serbian Language? with Latin letters and with Cyrillic letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518597/how-to-include-2-variants-of-serbian-language-with-latin-letters-and-with-cyril)

[Android localization values-** folder names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693209/android-localization-values-folder-names)

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) for more detailed supported language in Android

Answer (score 7):

It should be `values-b+sr+Latn`

Source: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/Locale.cpp;l=213;drc=e0930d324c9c35546d6940e0ddc8f3e0bd850614

Answer (score 1):

The name should be  "**values-sr**"

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Thanks. That should work however I was worried because of the Serbian Latin specification. If tomorrow I want to support Cyrillic (Serbian) Android studio will show the same option.

Comment: `values-sr` for Cyrillic, and `values-b+sr+Latn` for Latin.