# What does the "r" mean in the "nl-rNL" locale?

Tags: android, localization

I have a Android app project, and one of the locale dirs has the suffix `nl-rNL` and I was wondering what that `r` stands for. I know almost for sure that this isn't a typo, because the resource is actually used in the app.

I tried looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support), but couldn't find it.

Comment: I think this explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885951/3653544. Basically it means region

Comment: @Kevin thanks. Too bad it doesn't come with documentation references.